Absolute positioning on cover image background
I'm using an image as a background in a div. The image is positioned as center, no-repeat and has cover as size, and will  therefore show different sections when viewed on different screens/devices. Nothing strange about that.
I would like to position some markers on the image, and that those markers have absolute positions relative to the background image, regardless of the screen/device.

Is this even possible?
I've tried to position the markers as absolute and with percent positions but that, needless to say, didn't work.


<DIV style="width:100%;height:100vh;background-image: url('temp/bg.jpg');  background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

    <DIV style="position:absolute;top:82%;left:15%">Marker</DIV>

</DIV>




For a completely general solution I think you’ll need some JavaScript. Is that acceptable?

@a-haworth Yes, absolutely!

You need to define your image container as relative and the marker as absolute


 .background-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/id/491151340/photo/tractor-on-the-field.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=oOnIey9ftQpeafOhTqd7HigM9JEnLsnJZZpy3WhrLaE='); /* Replace with your image URL */
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            position: relative;
        }
        .marker {
            position: absolute;
            /* chose your position values */
            top: 82%; 
            left: 15%; 
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            background-color: red;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: white;
        }
 <div class="background-container">
        <div class="marker">Marker</div>
    </div>




thanks for the reply. When running tour code snippet, and then resizing the window, the marker moves around. When stretching to a narrow but tall window, the marker is under the tractor, when stretching to a wide but short window, the marker is behind the tractor. Unfortunately, this is the problem that I'm trying to solve ;-)

Don't use a background image, they do not resize the way you think in proportion to the screen.
Use an actual inline image in a container and absolute position your elements in relation to that container in percentage values.
Something like this.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.map {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.map img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.box {
  width: 8%;
  height: 8%;
  background-image: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/0/g/a/W/E/map-pin-red.svg);
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
}

#pin-1 {
  top: 29%;
  left: 36%;
}

.box:hover>.pin-text {
  display: block;
}

.pin-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 75%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
}

.pin-text h3 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
<div class="map">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/Pleasant_View_housing_development%2C_Missoula%2C_Montana_-_panoramio.jpg/800px-Pleasant_View_housing_development%2C_Missoula%2C_Montana_-_panoramio.jpg" alt="" />
  <div id="pin-1" class="box">
    <div class="pin-text">
      <h3>My House</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks for the reply. Your solution does in fact position the marker correctly when resizing the window. However, a 4x3 image on a mobile device will not fully fill the screen. I want the image to be 100% height and width regardless of screen dimensions.

Computing the size of a CSS sized object isn't trivial, and while CSS has gained a lot of math functions in the latest years I don't think it's yet possible to do all the calculations from there directly, so you'd need JS.
Some times ago I wrote a couple of answers on a similar problem for replaced elements, here is yet another adaptation for the most common case of CSS background. Note that it doesn't handle multiple background-images, nor does it support background-origin and probably many other cases, but it should provide a good enough ground for the ones in need.
It also requires you pass the size of the original image.


// Some helpers
function isRelative(length) {
  return length?.match?.(/%$/);
}
/**
 * Parses the component values of "object-position"
 * Returns the position in px
 */
function parsePositionAsPx(str, bboxSize, objectSize) {
  const num = parseFloat(str);
  if (isRelative(str)) {
    const ratio = num / 100;
    return (bboxSize * ratio) - (objectSize * ratio);
  }
  return num;
}
function parseObjectPosition(position, bbox, object) {
  const [left, top] = position.split(" ");
  return {
    left: parsePositionAsPx(left, bbox.width, object.width),
    top:  parsePositionAsPx(top, bbox.height, object.height)
   };
}
// Main function
function getBackgroundBBox(elem, object) {
  const { backgroundPosition, backgroundSize } = getComputedStyle(elem);
  const bbox   = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (backgroundSize === "contain") {
    const objectRatio = object.height / object.width;
    const bboxRatio   = bbox.height / bbox.width;
    const width  = bboxRatio > objectRatio ? bbox.width : bbox.height / objectRatio;
    const height = bboxRatio > objectRatio ? bbox.width * objectRatio : bbox.height;
    const {left, top} = parseObjectPosition(backgroundPosition, bbox, {width, height});
    return { left, top, width, height };
  }

  else if (backgroundSize === "cover") {
    const minRatio = Math.min(bbox.width / object.width, bbox.height / object.height);
    let width  = object.width  * minRatio;
    let height = object.height * minRatio;
    let outRatio  = 1;
    if (width < bbox.width) {
      outRatio = bbox.width / width;
    }
    if (Math.abs(outRatio - 1) < 1e-14 && height < bbox.height) {
      outRatio = bbox.height / height;
    }
    width  *= outRatio;
    height *= outRatio;
    
    const { left, top } = parseObjectPosition(backgroundPosition, bbox, {width, height});
    return { left, top, width, height };
  }
  else {
    let calcPos = parseObjectPosition(backgroundSize, bbox, { width: 0, height: 0 });
    const width = calcPos.left;
    const height = calcPos.top || width * (object.height / object.width);
    const { left, top } = parseObjectPosition(backgroundPosition, bbox, { width, height });
    return { left, top, width, height };
  }
}

// Example use
const object = { width: 1024, height: 682 }; // The original image's size
const markerPos = { x: 610, y: 342 }; // Your marker
const elem = document.querySelector(".background-container");
const recalc = () => {
  // Note that the bbox is relative to elem
  const bbox = getBackgroundBBox(elem, object);
  const ratioH = bbox.height / object.height;
  const ratioW = bbox.width / object.width;
  const top = (markerPos.y * ratioH) + bbox.top;
  const left = (markerPos.x * ratioW) + bbox.left;
  elem.style.setProperty("--top", `${top}px`);
  elem.style.setProperty("--left", `${left}px`);
  elem.style.setProperty("--scale", `${ratioW} ${ratioH}`);
};
// Apply at every resize
const obs = new ResizeObserver(([...entries]) => recalc());
obs.observe(elem);
// Test configuration
addEventListener("change", ({ target }) => {
  elem.style.setProperty(`--${target.name}`, target.value);
  recalc();
});
/* Shamelessly based on Hezy Ziv's answer */
.background-container {
  --bg-position: center;
  --bg-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/id/491151340/photo/tractor-on-the-field.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=oOnIey9ftQpeafOhTqd7HigM9JEnLsnJZZpy3WhrLaE=');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: var(--bg-position);
  background-size: var(--bg-size);
  position: relative;
}
.marker {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: center center;
  translate: -50% -50%;  
  background-color: #FF0000AA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: var(--top);
  left: var(--left);
  scale: var(--scale);
}
.config {
  position: fixed;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
}
<div class="background-container">
    <div class="marker">Marker</div>
</div>
<div class="config">
  <select name="bg-position">
    <option>center</option>
    <option>top left</option>
    <option>right bottom</option>
    <option>34px</option>
    <option>50px 7em</option>
  </select>
  <select name="bg-size">
    <option>cover</option>
    <option>contain</option>
    <option>25% 50%</option>
    <option>450px 600px</option>
  </select>
</div>




Using background-size:cover can be challenging because of the nature of it, regardless of screen size. 

Using an img tag instead of background-image helps you to achieve your goal. Than position it absolute in a relative container. Than ensure that the aspect  ratio of the image is preserved across different devices.

   
.html file

     <div class="image-container">
      <img src="assets/bg.jpg" alt="Background" class="background-image" />
      <div class="marker" style="top: 82%; left: 15%;">Marker</div>
    </div>


.css file
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh; 
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .background-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; 
  }
  
  .marker {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }


Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.
